# Display to be deleted records before deleting in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create and run .sql file tried searching online but no luck. tried below statements but getting error

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
SET SQLBLANCKLINES ON;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BELOW RECORDS WILL BE REMOVED');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE EMPLOYEE WHERE AREA LIKE ''mumbai''';
END;
/
```

Object is to display records before deleting them on screen

Comment: If you don't control multi-threading, you may end up displaying one set of rows, and then delete a *different* set of rows.

Comment: In one transaction, get exclusive locks on all tables involved, then `SELECT` and then `DELETE` with the same `WHERE` clause for both statements. Don't forget to commit.

Comment: I was thinking to run this in loop, may be like from the select query capture unique values, store in an array and loop through that array to show an entry and delete. Unable to find a way out. Will post if I find a solution.